# Update a spreadsheet cell value with Python

Tags: python, api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to update a value in Python, here is my code :

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

global values
global sheet
global SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID
global SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME

def connexion():
    # Some code ...
    # Call the Sheets API
    return service.spreadsheets()

def update(values, sheet, SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME):
    body = {
        'values': values
    }
    result = sheet.values().update(
    spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME, valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED', body=body).execute()
    if str(result.get('updatedCells')) != 0:
        return True
    return False

sheet = connexion()
values = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute().get('values', [])
for line in values:
    if line[3] == 'Hi !':
        line[5] == 'hello'
if update(values, sheet, SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME):
    print('   Update ok')
else:
    print('   Error')
```

I do not have any error but "Update ok" is printed. However, the value in the 6th cell line[5] is not updated... How can I do this please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the variable of `sheet` in your script can be used for getting and putting values to Google Spreadsheet, I think that your most script is correct. I think that there is only one modification point. The value of `line[5]` is compared with `hello` at `line[5] == 'hello'`. By this, `hello` is not put to `line[5]`. I think that the reason of your issue is this. So please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
line[5] == 'hello'
```

#### To:

```
line[5] = 'hello'
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the columns of `values` retrieved from `sheet.values().get()` is more than 6.